# Why do I get a "dead code" warning in this Java code?

Tags: java, dead-code

Would someone please tell me why i am getting a dead code warning in the else branch of `if (projectId != null)` ? If i got this right, the interpreter thinks `projectId` can never be null - is that right? In my opinion this is not possible...

```
Integer projectId = null;

if (!sprintTaskConnections.isEmpty())
    projectId = sprintTaskConnections.get(0).getProjectId();

// init name, state, startDate, endDate here

JiraSprint sprint = new JiraSprint(sprintInfo.getInt("id"), name, state, projectId, startDate, endDate);

if (projectId != null)
{
   ...
}
```

Even if i put a

```
sprintTaskConnections.add(new JiraSprintTaskConnection(1, 1, 1));
```

or a

```
sprintTaskConnections.clear();
```

in front of

```
if (!sprintTaskConnections.isEmpty())
projectId = sprintTaskConnections.get(0).getProjectId();
```

the result is always the same!

Please help me, i just don't get it at the moment!

Comment: Who is giving this warning? What interpreter do you mean?

Comment: You forgot to turn on the halting problem solver.

Comment: Is it just a warning?  The checks you are doing seem to be a smart design, so you could possibly just ignore the warning...but I'd need more detail on "if (!sprintTaskConnections.isEmpty())"

Comment: @nidhoeggr09 But what IDE / compiler are you using?

Comment: Maybe unrelated question, but why bother getting all the config information is the `sprintTaskConnections` is empty? You would know up front that its just going to fail throw a few lines later anyways...

Comment: @Dukeling: I am using the newest version of eclipse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have the `JiraSprint` code, so I can't confirm this, but I suspect the JiraSprint constructor takes an `int` where you pass in the projectId rather than an `Integer`. That forces Java to auto-unbox the Integer. If the Integer `projectId` is null, you'll get a `NullPointerException` (because of the auto-unboxing) there, so you won't even get to the if block. Therefore, projectId must not be null.

Comment: This is much more likely actually. +1.

Comment: You're my hero for the day! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:
`new JiraSprint(..)` gets `int projectId`?

In that case, if `projectId` is `null`, this line:

```
JiraSprint sprint = new JiraSprint(sprintInfo.getInt("id"), name, state, projectId, startDate, endDate);
```

will throw NPE, so `projectId` cannot be `null` after this line.

Answer (score -3):

projectId has a high chance that it will always be null so the code in the "if" will never get executed

Comment: But it's assigned here - `projectId = sprintTaskConnections.get(0).getProjectId();`.

Comment: only if !sprintTaskConnections.isEmpty()

Comment: No, if `sprintTaskConnections` is not empty, `projectId` will get a value assigned.

Comment: The dead code is the code inside the **else** part. Aka the compiler thinks `projectId` will NEVER be null

Comment: You are correct, i was completly missing the point there, TheTerribleSwiftTomato alreay pointed out the not-so-obvious